# Actualizar un campo del ultimo registro de una tabla con el id de otra tabla con un trigger

Tags: trigger, update, mysqldb

Tengo 2 tablas, "auth_user" y "hospital_usuario"

```
auth_user:
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| password     | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login   | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_superuser | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username     | varchar(150) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| first_name   | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name    | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(254) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_staff     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_joined  | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

hospital_usuario

+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Usuario      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Tipo_Usuario    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ID_Anth_User_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Quiero obtener el ultimo registro de la tabla "auth_user" del campo "id", y ese valor lo quiero insertar en el ultimo registro de la tabla "hospital_usuario" en el campo ID_Anth_User_id. El valor se tiene que actualizar después de insertar en la tabla auth_user

De momento tengo algo así

```
CREATE TRIGGER usuarios AFTER INSERT ON auth_user
  FOR EACH ROW   
    UPDATE hospital_usuario SET ID_Anth_User_id = auth_user.id
```

No se como obtener el ultimo registro del campo "id" de la tabla "auth_user"para insertarlo en el ultimo registro del campo "ID_Anth_User_id " de la tabla "hospital_usuario "

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Una pregunta de BD sin la definición de las tablas, datos de prueba y lo que lleves del trigger siempre será una pregunta sin un ejemplo mínimo verificable. Y ojalá puedas editar y añadir esto **como texto** para que otros puedan probar y ayudar a corregir tu código

Comment: Sorry, es que estaba trabajando en otra computadora y guarde para seguir con la pregunta desde otro ordenado, pero a hora si ya termine de completar la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estas creando un TRIGGER AFTER INSERT sobre la tabla auth_user, eso significa que el trigger se ejecuta cuando se inserta un nuevo registro, por logica el ultimo registro será el que se esta insertando en ese momento.

Los trigger de MySQL proveen la variable NEW para que puedas sacar la información del registro que se estar insertando, NEW sera la ultima fila de la tabla auth_user en este caso

```
CREATE TRIGGER usuarios AFTER INSERT ON auth_user
  FOR EACH ROW   
    UPDATE hospital_usuario SET ID_Anth_User_id = NEW.id
```

> Solo deberías tener cuidado que estas ejecutando un UPDATE sin un WHERE y actualizaria todos los registros de la tabla, considera poner algun tipo de condición para ser mas especifico con que filas quieres actualizar

Comment: Bueno solo me faltaba el NEW, y lo que no supe fue como tomar el ultimo registro de la tabla "hospital_usuario", pero lo pude resolver de otra forma